# How to create a table from avro schema (.avsc)?

Tags: python, pyspark, avro, databricks

I have an avro schema file and I need to create a table in Databricks through pyspark. I don't need to load the data, just want to create the table. The easy way is to load the JSON string and take the `"name"` and `"type"` from `fields` array. Then generate the `CREATE` SQL query. I want to know if there is any programmatic way to do that with any API. Sample schema -

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "kylosample",
  "doc" : "Schema generated by Kite",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "registration_dttm",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '2016-02-03T07:55:29Z'"
  }, {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '1'"
  }, {
    "name" : "first_name",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'Amanda'"
  }, {
    "name" : "last_name",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'Jordan'"
  }, {
    "name" : "email",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'ajordan0@com.com'"
  }, {
    "name" : "gender",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'Female'"
  }, {
    "name" : "ip_address",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '1.197.201.2'"
  }, {
    "name" : "cc",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '6759521864920116'",
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "country",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'Indonesia'"
  }, {
    "name" : "birthdate",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '3/8/1971'"
  }, {
    "name" : "salary",
    "type" : [ "null", "double" ],
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '49756.53'",
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "title",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'Internal Auditor'"
  }, {
    "name" : "comments",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '1E+02'"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be available via Python API yet ... This is how I have done it in the past by creating an external table via Spark SQL pointing to your exported .avsc since you only want to create a table and not load any data ... example:

```py
spark.sql("""
create external table db.table_name
STORED AS AVRO
LOCATION 'PATH/WHERE/DATA/WILL/BE/STORED'
TBLPROPERTIES('avro.schema.url'='PATH/TO/SCHEMA.avsc')
""")
```

The native Scala API in Spark 2.4 looks to have .avsc reader available now ... since you are using Databricks you can change your kernel in the notebook like `%scala or %python or %sql` ... Scala example:

```scala
import org.apache.avro.Schema

val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("user.avsc"))

spark
  .read
  .format("avro")
  .option("avroSchema", schema.toString)
  .load("/tmp/episodes.avro")
  .show()
```

Reference Docs for Spark 2.4 Avro Integration =>

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#configuration

https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/30/apache-avro-as-a-built-in-data-source-in-apache-spark-2-4.html

Comment: Getting an error `unable to infer schema. The schema specification is required to create the table`

Comment: are you generating the avro schema from your avro files?  ex: => ```avro-tools getschema part-m-00000.avro > orders.avsc```